# How can I retrieve ETH that was sent to my MetaMask wallet from coinbase and my Exodus wallet but were never deposited?

Tags: wallets, cpp-ethereum

I sent ETH from my coinbase and exodus wallets to my metamask wallet but the coins were not deposited. How can I trace and retrieve the coins?

Comment: Do you have a transaction hash? You can look up in a block explorer like https://etherscan.io/ o https://www.etherchain.org/. Otherwise you have to contact your exchange support.

Answer (score 0):

1. make sure you are on the main network in MetaMask
   [image: like this:]
2. Find a transactionID of your transaction, and look it up on [Etherscan](https://etherscan.io/). There you sould find information about your transaction - there was a lot going on on the network over the last hours, maybe it didn't get through. But in that case, the Ether should "reappear" on your wallets in coinbase and exodus, as they shouldn't have left at all (until the transaction was actually successfull).

Comment: Thank you. I am new to this and I haven't gotten over the learning curve. Does the gas limit supposed to show show on metamask when I send an ETH?

Comment: you actually should be good to go with the default values, but for a regular transaction ("sending Ether") from account A to account B you should be good with the default values.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the ethereum development. Though you have got the things sorted out I am trying to answer your real question. If you want to trace the funds that you send, you can do that with one of the three things

1. Sending Address
2. Receiving Address
3. Transaction Address

put any one of those in [etherscan](https://etherscan.io) and that will give you all the information required.